# Number of quadratic residues for $p=4k+3$ and $p=4k+1$ less than $p/2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

I know the number of quadratic residues less than $p/2$ for $p=4k+1$ is $p+1/4$, would it be the same result for $p=4k+3$?

Comment: Check your data. I think it should be $(p-1)/4$ when $p\equiv1\pmod 4$. It cannot be $(p-1)/4$ when $p\equiv3\pmod4$ because that is not an integer. Also, for how many primes $p$ have you checked this by hand? Do share your data!!

Answer (score 3):

For $p=4k+1$, the number of quadratic residues less than $\frac{p}{2}$ is $\frac{p-1}{4}$. In other words there are equal numbers of them less than  $\frac{p}{2}$ and more than  $\frac{p}{2}$. This follows from the fact that $-1$ is a quadratic residue and therefore each quadratic residue $i$ is paired with a quadratic residue $p-i$.

There is no simple result for $p=4k+3$. However, if you check various primes, you will find that for these primes  more than half the residues are less than $\frac{p}{2}$.